# Using the jcharset library

Tags: android, character-encoding

I have added to the build path the [jcharset](http://www.freeutils.net/source/jcharset/) library and in my code I am trying to create a new string from another with the GSM charset of the lirary.

```
   String example_string new String(another_string.getBytes("SCGSM"));
```

But that part of the code gives me the exception:

```
   java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: SCGSM
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you using obfuscator like Proguard while building your `.apk` ?

Comment: did you find a solution for it? I am facing the same problem while using "SCGSM" with Oracle Java8

Answer (score 0):

If you are using oracles JRE then Jcharset library should be in jre/lib/ext directory.
This is an open bug in oracles implementation.

[ref of bug](https://www.freeutils.net/source/jcharset/)